# How can I make the code follow another link after the first one?

Tags: python-3.x, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to find the link at position 3 of the url (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 4 times. At the end I want to print the final link.

The issue that I am running into is getting the url to repeat. Please give me some advice how I can make this code run.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re
lst = list()
lst2 = list()
count = 0
# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'
count = int(input('Enter Count '))
position = int(input('Enter Position ')) -1
while count >= 0:
    html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        values = tag.get('href', None)
        values = str(values)
        lst.append(values)
        count = count - 1
        lst2.append(lst[position:position+1])
        url = lst2[0]
        url = str(url)
        print(re.findall('http.+html',url))
        lst.clear()
        lst2.clear()
    return url
```

Comment: You are returning `url` at the end of your first loop. Could you change the indentation to match the `while count >= 0` line?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to read a first URL, get the link at the `position`-th place (3rd in your case), then read that second URL, and repeat `count` times (4 times in your case). (BTW, you don't need `lst` and `lst2`; they just confuse the code right now.)

Comment: Yes you are correct this is the code that finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

If I am parsing your question correctly, one way to do this (I'll leave error checking as an exercise for you; also code has not been run) is like this:

```
# Loop count times; "_" effectively means ignore the counter
for _ in range(count):
    # Get an array of <a> elements,
    #   then get the (position-1)th
    #   then get the text of the 'href' tag
    next_url = soup.find_all('a')[position-1]['href']
    # And repeat for the URL found there
    html = urlopen(next_url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Finally, print out the (position-1)th URL on the last page
print(soup.find_all('a')[position-1]['href'])
```

Of course, if there are not enough links on the page, or there are `<a>` tags without an `href`, or the `href` URL is malformed the program will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question after playing with the code for a little while longer. I am sure there is a much more eloquent solution, but I am really happy I finally got it to run correctly.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re
lst = list()
count = 0
# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html'
count = int(input('Enter Count '))
position = int(input('Enter Position ')) -1
while True:
    html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        values = tag.get('href', None)
        values = str(values)
        lst.append(values)
    url = str(lst[position:position+1])
    url = url[2:-2]
    print(url)
    lst.clear()
    count = count -1
    if count == 0:break
```